# Монтевидео / видео

Tags: недопустимая-метка

Почему в слове Монтевидео "д" твёрдое, тогда как в "видео" мягкое?

Answer (score 2):

На вопрос "почему?" ответ - по словарю, специальному.

[Словарь имён собственных](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BE)

> Монтевидео [тэ, дэ], *нескл.* (столица Уругвая)

И потом, зачем сопоставлять топоним (пишущийся и слышащийся **"как договорились"**) [с отраслью или её средствами](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BE), где "д" смягчается последующим "е" **по правилам**?

Для самообразования - читать: [Проблема звука [Э] после твёрдых согласных](https://lingvoforum.net/index.php?topic=80570.0).

Цитата-завлекалка (в тему-проблему-дискуссию):

> ...После твёрдых согласных пишется буква "Е", что полностью
>   противоречит фонѐматическому принципу русской орфографии - "как
>   пишется, так и произносится". Из-за этого прочтение вслух незнакомых
>   иностранных слов вызывает затруднения: как же в них правильно
>   произнести согласный перед "Е" - твёрдо или мягко? Существует,
>   например, такое слово аллитѐрация (повторение одинаковых или
>   однородных согласных в стихотворении) - почему оно внезапно должно
>   произноситься с твёрдым [ТЭ], в то время как однокоренные литера,
>   литература, транслитерация звучат мягко? А почему слово дѐкор
>   произносится твёрдо, если производное от него декорация - с мягким
>   [ДЕ]? Ну что это за словесный маразм такой???